# Test class not working

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I want to write test class for this:

```
public class UpdateAccountAddresses {
    Map<id,account>updateShippingAddressMap =new Map<id,Account>{};
    Map<id,Account> updateBillingAddressMap =new Map<id,Account>();
    set<id>AccountSetId=new Set<Id>{};
    list<contact> conlist=new list<contact>();

    public void RunOnUpdate(map<id,Account>NewMap,Map<id,Account>OldMap){
        for(id aid:newmap.keySet()){
            AccountSetId.add(aid);
            account newAccount=(Account)newmap.get(aid);
            account OldAccount=(Account)oldmap.get(aid);
            if(newAccount.ShippingCountry!=oldAccount.ShippingCountry || 
               newaccount.ShippingCity!=oldAccount.ShippingCity )  
            {
                contact con=new contact(lastname='testforAcc',accountid=aid);
                conList.add(con);
            }
        }
        insert conlist;
    }
}
```

I started with the below code but am not able to proceed.

```
@isTest
    public class UpdateAccountAddresses_Test {

    static  testmethod void runTest(){
            Account acc=new Account(name='testAccount',ShippingCity='Delhi',ShippingCountry='India');
            insert acc;
          acc.ShippingCity='jaypur';
            update acc;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for my Trigger

```
  trigger AccountExampl on Account (before update) {
UpdateAccountAddresses upd=new UpdateAccountAddresses();
    upd.RunOnUpdate(trigger.newMap,trigger.oldMap);
}
```

Comment: From where are you invoking this class. If It's trigger, then  can you mention your trigger

Comment: I have added my trigger ..Here the code coverage is 100% for both class and trigger,but i am not sure it is correct test class.I want to add the conditions to check old and new shiipingcity ..then contact created or not.How can i achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.assertEquals() to check whether your required contact is created or not.

```
    @isTest
public class UpdateAccountAddresses_Test {

     static  testmethod void runTest(){
            Account acc=new Account(name='testAccount',ShippingCity='Delhi',ShippingCountry='India');
            insert acc;
            system.assertEquals(0,[Select Count() from Contact Where AccountId = :acc.Id],'A contact was created on insert when it should not have been');
            acc.ShippingCity='jaypur';
            update acc;

            system.assertEquals(1,[Select Count() from Contact Where AccountId = :acc.Id],'A contact was NOT created on insert when it should have been');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Updated your asserts to be able to work when the contact name is changed from "testForAcc" in the live code. Hope you do not mind

Answer (score 0):

As well as writing your test, best to remove unused lines of code and use a local variable instead of a class field:

```
public class UpdateAccountAddresses {

    public void RunOnUpdate(map<id,Account>NewMap,Map<id,Account>OldMap){
        list<contact> conlist=new list<contact>();
        for(id aid:newmap.keySet()){
            account newAccount=(Account)newmap.get(aid);
            account OldAccount=(Account)oldmap.get(aid);
            if(newAccount.ShippingCountry!=oldAccount.ShippingCountry || 
               newaccount.ShippingCity!=oldAccount.ShippingCity )  
            {
                contact con=new contact(lastname='testforAcc',accountid=aid);
                conList.add(con);
            }
        }
        insert conlist;
    }
}
```